# I don't get the GUID property in my model when I make the derivative

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-navisworks

I want to obtain the GUID property of my model when I make a derivative, my question is if I have to make a modification to the model before making the derivative? Or is there a function that generates this property?

this is the property that can be seen in the navisworks
[modelo in navisworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ecea.png)
(originally the model did not have the GUID property, this was added recently, I don't know if that influences the error of not showing me that property)

this is my model after performing the derivative[modelo in derivative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpWNe.png)

i hope i get this is another model where if it shows me the GUID property[another model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4zR7.png)

Comment: Please check if the model doesn't have the GUID is a SVF2 model by checking `outputType` in the manifest via [GET manifest](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET) and may I know when this model got translated?

Comment: if model is .dwf "progress": "complete", "outputType": "svf2", "status":"success" . 
Regarding when the model was translated, I do not have that information

Comment: As we can see `"outputType": "svf2",`, so it's an SVF2 model. But unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this issue.  [DWF-Direct-Translation-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a942r.png), [DWF-Direct-Translation-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irrHg.png) and [DWF2NWC-Translation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTBus.jpg)

Comment: There was an issue related to `Item.GUID` in SVF2, but it's been fixed for a while. So, could you **rename** your source DWF file, upload to APS and translate it to SVF2 to see if it's reproducible? If this issue presissts on your side, please consider sharing a reproducible model to `aps (DOT) help (AT) autodesk (DOT) com` for investigations.

Comment: Thank you very much I was able to solve the problem by saving it in another format in .nwd

Comment: Nice, thanks for sharing the good news!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much, I was able to solve the problem by changing the format from .dwf to .nwd